# What is the difference between graphical abstract and graphical table of contents?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

I was curious about Wiley's manuscript submission process. It says to *upload an image and graphical abstract for the graphical table of contents*. In the drop-down menu of file uploads, there are three options- image, graphical abstract, and graphical table of contents.

Can anyone clarify what exactly are these three things that need to be uploaded? I quote the instructions from the publishers themselves:

> you must upload a graphic to be included in the online table of
>   contents and a statement outlining the paper’s novelty with the
>   original manuscript. The graphic should be .tiff or .eps format and be
>   uploaded to the Graphical Table of Content. The novelty statement should include the paper title, the authors’ names (with the corresponding author indicated by an asterisk), and no more than 80 words or 3 sentences of text summarizing the paper’s novelty.

Comment: Have you looked at recent papers published by the journal? What have other authors done?

Comment: @avid The question is about the submission form, not the content of the submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upload the required image and text, the journal staff will figure it out and it will be fine.

- Image:  This is the TIFF or EPS file.
- Graphical abstract:  This is the text.
- Graphical table of contents:  This appears to be an error.  Perhaps you can upload a file containing both the image and text in this category, but there is no need to do that.

Comment: The graphical table of contents is what they do using the various image/graphical abstracts. It is the content of the journal not that of an individual paper.